# Why does my sed script not replace fields correctly

Tags: bash, sed

I have a short bash script in which I use sed to replace 4 digit and 2 digit string with variables. The way I have done it does not give the wanted result.
Fields to be replaced

```
start_date = '2023-01-25_00:00:00','2023-01-25_00:00:00',
end_date   = '2023-01-26_00:00:00','2023-01-26_00:00:00',
```

The script

```
#!/bin/bash
year="2023"
month="01"
day="25"
hour="00"

fclen="2"
end_day=$(date +%d -d "$(date) + $fclen day")
end_year=$(date +%Y -d "$(date) + $fclen day")
end_month=$(date +%m -d "$(date) + $fclen day")
sed -i -e "s/^\s* start_date/ start_date = '${year}-${month}-${day}_00:00:00','${year}-${month}-${day}_00:00:00',/g" -e "s/^\s* end_date/ end_date   = '${end_year}-${end_month}-${end_day}_00:00:00',${end_year}-${end_month}-${end_day}_00:00:00',/g" ./namelist.wps
```

the result

```
 start_date = '2023-01-25_00:00:00', = '2023-01-25_00:00:00', = '2023-01-25_00:00:00','2023-01-25_00:00:00',
end_date   = '2023-01-28_00:00:00',   = '2023-01-28_00:00:00',   = '2023-01-26_00:00:00','2023-01-26_00:00:00',
```

Why is the "=" sign being repeated. There must be a way of going directly for the figures instead of giving the whole line to be replaced. This I cannot figure out.
I will appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You're only replacing `start_date`, not the entire

```
start_date = '2023-01-25_00:00:00','2023-01-25_00:00:00',
```

You need to change the regexp to match the dates after the keyword.

```
sed -i -e "s/^\s* start_date\s*=\s*'[^']*','[^']*',/ start_date = '${year}-${month}-${day}_00:00:00','${year}-${month}-${day}_00:00:00',/g" -e "s/^\s* end_date\s*=\s*'[^']*','[^']*',/ end_date = '${end_year}-${end_month}-${end_day}_00:00:00',${end_year}-${end_month}-${end_day}_00:00:00',/g" ./namelist.wps
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar. You have really saved my day. This does exactly what I want.